# NestJS's Server URL cannot be accessed from Ionic App running on phone

Tags: ionic4, nestjs

I have a NestJS server and Ionic app. During development, these two apps do not have any errors when communicating with each other. Deployed my Ionic app to my phone, but now it doesn't communicate with my server upon testing. I have my NestJS's server URL set as `http://<myLaptopIP>:3000` on my Ionic app. I also tried accessing that URL from my phone's browser, but it also doesn't work. I already have CORS enabled in my NestJS app with default configurations, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Do you have your laptop's port exposed to incoming traffic?

Comment: I recently tried that. Opened port 3000 to private and public networks. Still no luck.

Comment: When you open the IONIC app on your phone, are you on WIFI?

Comment: Yes, I'm on the same WIFI network as my laptop.